# Index the first and the last rows with NA in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large dataset, which contains many NAs. I want to find the rows where the first NA and the last NA appear. For example, for column A, I want the output to be the second row (the last NA before a number) and the fifth row (the first NA after a number). My code, which was shown below, does not work very well.

```
nonnaindex <- which(!is.na(df))
firstnonna <- apply(nonnaindex, 2, min)
```

Data:

```
ID  A   B   C
1   NA  NA  3
2   NA  2   2
3   3   3   1
4   4   5   NA
5   NA  6   NA
```

Comment: What if you have `NA 2 NA NA, 3, NA NA 3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this function might be what you are looking for:

```
first_and_last_non_na <- function(DT, col) {
  library(data.table)
  data.table(DT)[, grp := rleid(is.na(get(col)))][
    , rbind(last(.SD[is.na(get(col)) & grp == min(grp)]),
            first(.SD[is.na(get(col)) & grp == max(grp)]))][
              !is.na(ID)][, grp := NULL][]
}
```

which returns

```
first_and_last_na_row(DT, "A")
```

> ```
>    ID  A B  C
> 1:  2 NA 2  2
> 2:  5 NA 6 NA
> ```

```
first_and_last_na_row(DT, "B")
```

> ```
>    ID  A  B C
> 1:  1 NA NA 3
> ```

```
first_and_last_na_row(DT, "C")
```

> ```
>    ID A B  C
> 1:  4 4 5 NA
> ```

```
first_and_last_na_row(DT, "D")
```

> ```
> Empty data.table (0 rows) of 4 cols: ID,A,B,C
> ```

in case of

```
DT
```

> ```
>    ID  A  B  C
> 1:  1 NA NA  3
> 2:  2 NA  2  2
> 3:  3  3  3  1
> 4:  4  4  5 NA
> 5:  5 NA  6 NA
> ```

or

```
first_and_last_na_row(DT2, "D")
```

> ```
>    ID  A  B C  D
> 1:  1 NA NA 3 NA
> ```

in case of [Akrun's (simplified) example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45882667/index-the-first-and-the-last-rows-with-na-in-a-dataframe/45883754#comment78724320_45882667)

```
DT2
```

> ```
>    ID  A  B  C  D
> 1:  1 NA NA  3 NA
> 2:  2 NA  2  2  2
> 3:  3  3  3  1 NA
> 4:  4  4  5 NA NA
> 5:  5 NA  6 NA  4
> ```

#### Edit: Faster version using `melt()`

The OP has [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45882667/index-the-first-and-the-last-rows-with-na-in-a-dataframe/45883754#comment78731092_45883754) that his production data set consists of 4000 columns and 192 rows and that he needs the indices to clean another data set. He tried a  `for` loop across all columns which is very slow.

Therefore, I suggest to reshape the data set from  wide to long format and to use `data.table`'s efficient grouping mechanism:

```
# reshape from wide to long format
long <- setDT(DT2)[, melt(.SD, id = "ID")][
  # add grouping variable to distinguish streaks continuous of NA/non-NA values 
  # for each variable
  , grp := rleid(variable, is.na(value))][
    # set sort order just for convenience, not essential
    , setorder(.SD, variable, ID)]
long
```

> ```
>     ID variable value grp
>  1:  1        A    NA   1
>  2:  2        A    NA   1
>  3:  3        A     3   2
>  4:  4        A     4   2
>  5:  5        A    NA   3
>  6:  1        B    NA   4
>  7:  2        B     2   5
>  8:  3        B     3   5
>  9:  4        B     5   5
> 10:  5        B     6   5
> 11:  1        C     3   6
> 12:  2        C     2   6
> 13:  3        C     1   6
> 14:  4        C    NA   7
> 15:  5        C    NA   7
> 16:  1        D    NA   8
> 17:  2        D     2   9
> 18:  3        D    NA  10
> 19:  4        D    NA  10
> 20:  5        D     4  11
> ```

Now, we get the indices of the starting or ending, resp., `NA` sequence for each variable (if any) by

```
# starting NA sequence
long[, .(ID = which(is.na(value) & grp == min(grp))), by = variable]
```

> ```
>    variable ID
> 1:        A  1
> 2:        A  2
> 3:        B  1
> 4:        D  1
> ```

```
# ending NA sequence
long[, .(ID = which(is.na(value) & grp == max(grp))), by = variable]
```

> ```
>    variable ID
> 1:        A  5
> 2:        C  4
> 3:        C  5
> ```

Note that this returns all indices of the starting or ending `NA` sequences which might be more convenient for subsequent cleaning of another data set. If only the last and first indices are required this can be achieved by

```
long[long[, is.na(value) & grp == min(grp), by =variable]$V1, .(ID = max(ID)), by = variable]
```

> ```
>    variable ID
> 1:        A  2
> 2:        B  1
> 3:        D  1
> ```

```
long[long[, is.na(value) & grp == max(grp), by =variable]$V1, .(ID = min(ID)), by = variable]
```

> ```
>    variable ID
> 1:        A  5
> 2:        C  4
> ```

I have tested this approach using a dummy data set of 192 rows times 4000 columns. The whole operation *needed less than one second*.

Comment: That works. Since I have more than 4000 columns, I have to use a for loop on top your function. Is there a less time-consuming route?

Comment: If all or most columns have the same data type it is likely that data generally should be stored in long format (database "style") rather than wide format (spreadsheet style). In long format, column names become variables and are easier to handle for aggregation.Final result can then be reshaped to wide format again. BTW: How many rows do you have?

Comment: I have 192 rows. The reason that I want to index it is because another dataset has the same row * column. Once I have the index of NAs of this dataframe, I need to use it to clean up another dataframe.

Comment: I have added a version which is _much_ faster for many columns than calling the function repeatedly. Hope this will play nicely with your subsequent cleaning step of another data set.